# Roughly what levels should my party be at for fighting Shadow Mitsuo?

Tags: persona-4-golden

I've already looked up some strategies for the boss, but I've been beaten several times without managing to lower the "main" form's HP very much. I can't seem to squeeze in enough damage to stop the boss from rebuilding his "Hero" form, and then Gigadyne eventually gets the better of me.

For the first attempt I used the original four Investigation Team members, and then I swapped out Yosuke for Teddie to make healing HP and Fear/Exhaustion easier, which helped.

[The party's levels are 30-37.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmJ3x.jpg)
I'm guessing there's a lot of grinding ahead of me; which members should I focus on leveling up, and what levels should I shoot for? Any advice to speed up grinding and/or lessen potential for frustration is welcome, too.

While I'm asking, I'd also like to know how far into the story I am, roughly. This is my first ever run through the game, and although I've been playing casually I've taken three years to get this far. Without spoiling much of what's ahead (I'm aware that there are multiple endings but don't know what the criteria to get them are), I'd like an estimate of how many more playing hours are left to reach a good ending.

Comment: Level is not terribly important for Shadow Mitsuo, just go into the boss fight at a minimum of level 38 and have the Persona black frost. He will destroy the boss. I would also recommend a party of yukiko, yosuke and chie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shadow Mitsuo is level 45, so it would be safest to be a few levels above that. Depending on your difficulty (if you're, say, on Normal or Easy) you could probably get away with a little less than 45.

After beating Shadow Mitsuo, you'll be around the halfway point of the game factoring in the True Ending.

There is no real trick to grinding to make it faster that isn't highly situational and out of your control (ie Arcana Chance). 
(Edit: Though there are some EXP boosting items that you can get from End-Game fishing, though this requires maxing the Hermit Social Link)

If you haven't already, be sure to revisit dungeons you've already cleared to beat the optional bosses for some good exp, a special item and some bonus Courage.

Edit: Also, party EXP is divided between party members, so if there is a specific party member you want to level up, bring them without anyone else and both them and your MC will effectively be getting double EXP. Going with just the MC will also give him quadruple EXP but that's usually very risky outside of NG+.